# What does adding し to an adjective do?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

For example:

> 楽しいししたいよ～

The し is added to 楽しい. What does it do?

Comment: This 「し」 should be found in every dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[goo辞書 ①［接助］2](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/92431/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%97/)

> 前に挙げた事柄を原因・理由として下の事柄に続ける意を表す。から。ので。「身体はじょうぶです―、もっと働けます」「家も近いんだ―、たまには寄れよ」

Thus, 楽しいししたいよ～ means "I want to do it 'cause it's fun".